# Laravel get view name of rendered route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is here a way to achieve that : 
I want to check in AppServiceProvider, name of rendered view.

So, for example :

1. User enters at  `/home`, for that route in controller it `return view('website.home');`
2. From AppServiceProvider get current route, and get view name that is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that it's possible to get the view name in the `AppServiceProvider`, as that runs prior to a view being created in the route's respective controller method. You can get the name of the view within the controller, however, after it's been created:

```
$view = view('website.home');
$name = $view->getName();
return $view;
```

The current route name is accessible within the service provider using:

```
request()->route()->getName();

// or

Request::getCurrentName();
```

**edit**

Actually this would probably be doable with a view composer and a wildcard match on the view:

```
// AppServiceProvider boot method
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        view()->share('viewName', $view->getName());
    });
}
```